# how to Start keycloak 18 in Https mode in Kubernetes(minikube) Getting error to get the certificate

Tags: java, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm running a minikube cluster on my local machine And want to deploy keycloak 18 version via Helm chart. But I'm unknown about. How to Add Generated certficates to my Keycloak Container.

Here is my Yaml file for Keycloak. I tried like this but gave Error :

```
 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) Key material not provided to setup HTTPS. Please configure your keys/certificates or start the server
```

**YAML file**

```
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          args: {{ .Values.args }}
          env:
          - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
            value: {{ .Values.cred.User }}
          - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
            value: {{ .Values.cred.Password }}
          - name: KC_PROXY
            value: "edge"
          - name: KC_HOSTNAME
            value: keycloak.192.168.59.150.nip.io:8443
          - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
            value: /home/user/keycloak/crt/example.crt
          - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
            value: /home/user/keycloak/crt/example.key
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: https
            containerPort: 8443
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
```

**Where should I give the Certificates/Keys path to my keycloak Container**

**MY keycloak Helm structure and i have added all the Certificates in crt directory**

```
keycloak
├── Chart.lock
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
├── crt
│   ├── example.crt
│   ├── example.csr
│   ├── example.key
│   └── example_public.key
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── hpa.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── service.yaml
│   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   └── tests
│       └── test-connection.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Comment: Can anyone Check this Question @kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

```
name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
        value: /home/user/keycloak/crt/example.crt
      - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
        value: /home/user/keycloak/crt/example.key
```

Make sure that the certificat and the key paths are correct.
I suggest you copy them inside before.
I suggest you to build your own image with docker:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY . .
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD admin
ENTRYPOINT [ "keycloak-17.0.1/bin/kc.sh","start","--https-certificate- 
file=yourfilecert.pem","--https-certificate-key- 
file=yourkeyfile.key","--hostname=yourhostname"]
```

After build your image :`docker build . -t yourtag:version`